# What is the best and easiest method to create simple concrete road bridge?

Tags: modeling

Its been a while since I last (5 months) used Blender having only ever using it for the first time 9 months ago so I am a still a newbie.
I want to create a very simple dual lane (total 4 lanes of traffic) concrete bridge similar to a real one and wonder if I should 'construct' the main deck using a SINGLE simple mesh cube with appropriate dimensions (300 meters long, 20.5 meters wide) and then apply mesh planes for the road surface or construct it using multiple mesh cubes, one for each lane of traffic and one for the pedestrian paths each side and one for the center median strip between the opposite flowing traffic lanes.
I am not interested in a complex model as it will only ever be 'viewed' from a distance.

Here is an image of the real thing.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would do one segment (with the pillar) and array it as many times as necessary with the Array modifier, and use an image texture for the texture and for the white lines on the road

Comment: You can make half the road (one side and 2 lanes), and then use a mirror modifier, before using the array, like moonboots suggested. That way , you might be able to construct the entire road (or the majority of it) by only making half of one "segment".

Comment: Thanks moonboots and Chris - I am sure you both have helped me out before. I wasn't aware of the mirror modifier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is create just one segment of your bridge. As Christopher says, you can use a *Mirror* to make it symmetrical:

[image]

Then use an *Array* modifier to repeat it as much as needed:

[image]

If the bridge was curvy you would use a *Curve* modifier after the *Array*. If it was curvy and going up and down on Z, the pillars would need another method though (like *Instancing*) as you want them to stay vertical.

Comment: Thanks again. I have taken a Google street view of the bridge and added it to the initial post. There is a median strip (I will only use half the width for the mirror image) a 'bollard' to separate traffic lanes from pedestrian walkway (I will only add that as a simple rectangle and no rail at the top) as it won't be viewed close enough to see) and a wire mesh fence (so that pedestrians don't fall off the edge) courtesy of free model from turbo squid which is very similar.

Comment: so what you could do is use several objects and array each of them, for example the railing may be another object than the pillar+road. Or you array the railing, merge it with the pillar+road, etc... many possible solutions here. The fact that your road is completely straight makes it simpler

Comment: @JohnArnold Mirror and Array are the way I would do it, too. The only thing when using the Array modifier to keep in mind: if you use a _Relative Offset_ of 1, Blender will put the segments one after another, or to be more precise: one bounding box width away from the previous segment. If you do things like lamp posts as separate objects, a relative offset of 1 will put each post directly next to another. So you should either join them to the main segment, or use a _Constant Offset_ fitting the size of the main segment. For example, if the segment is 5 m long, then set the offset to 5 m.

Comment: Thanks. I also remember your name Gordon and I have used arrays before a few times and so am confident using them but thanks for reminding me.  Are you all suggesting that I only create a short section of the bridge (which is 300 metres long) and then using an array to 'build' it to 300 metres? I was going to create it with mesh cubes 300 metres long. I also have street lamps courtesy of Turbo squid which appear to be spaced every 50 meters apart but offset from one side to the other. Hey didn't I say that I didn't want it too complex as it will only be viewed from the air (via a flight sim)?

Comment: yes, create a segment then array it, or array several separate objects, seems like the way to go

Comment: @JohnArnold Sure, you are totally free to not use the Array modifier, whatever seems to be easiest for you. Of course if you just create some profile which stretches out over 300 m it might be best to make it one piece. The only advantage of the modifier is, if you have something that repeats itself every 5 meters and after finishing the bridge you decide you want it a bit different. Then you don't have to change it about 60 times for the 300 m, you just change it once and the array does the rest of the work. Street lamps could then be placed with a constant offset of 50 m separately.

Comment: There is one advantage I can think of creating a short section and use an array to 'expand' it to 300 metres. I then have a 'model' for a similar bridge of a different length as the design of this bridge is very similar to many other bridges in Australia.  BTW how do I close this question - 'answer your question'? and how do I attach a blender file so that you can see what I have done so far?

Comment: You don't have to close, just accept the right answer with the check mark. If you want to share your file, edit your original question and use a site like https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @Gordon Brinkman   I took your advice to create half the width of my bridge to later use mirror however I can't work out how to achieve the mirror. After a few difference attempts I now assume that I have to JOIN all the meshes which make up the half bridge (as when I tried it would only mirror one of the meshes) BUT when I attempted to join all the meshes (select All then ctrl J) I lost all of my arrays yet I have APPLY checked on each different array. Please advise the method. Thanks

Comment: @JohnArnold The _Mirror_ modifier works like every modifier only on the object which has the modifier. And modifiers are used for non-destructive workflows, which means whatever you modify will not be permanent and disappear when the modifier is removed unless applied on the object. Merging objects that have different modifiers will result in losing all modifiers except those on the active object. Even having the same modifiers but different settings will result in having a merged object with the settings of what was active object before merge. You lost the arrays although you applied them?

Comment: @Gordon Brinkman I have added my model above. I am wondering if my problem is caused by the fact that the fence is created with an array of a (fence) object which has a post on one side only plus a single (fence) object which has posts on either side to complete the fence as when I attempt to go to edit mode with all selected the array of fences panels disappears and only the single double posted fence remains. Should I JOIN these? What is exactly the method to add a mirror modifier for this particular object (total bridge). I have added an image to demonstrate the fence with a gap.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkman I think that I have worked out what I did wrong. I had forgot to select APPLY twice on my arrays to actually apply them. I thought that when Apply was ticked then the array was applied. It has been a long time since I last used Blender and modifiers and then it was not long after I first set eyes on Blender.

Comment: @JohnArnold What do you mean by "when Apply was ticked"? You mean that tickmark symbol left to the word _Apply_? That's just a graphical representation of what it does if you click it... it doesn't mean there's anything applied yet (or else the modifier would have been gone). The triangles pointing up and down next to the words _Move to First_ and _Move to Last_ also don't the modifiers are constantly moving up and down all the time because the symbols are visible... 

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann YES. I assumed incorrectly that the tick meant that it was selected/applied (and that it could be unticked as in other applications ). I now see that when it is double clicked it then is applied and the modifier displayed is removed. I find that a little confusing especially that after it is really applied you would not have any idea that a modifier had been applied - or can you? I have never looked at any of the other symbols.

Comment: @JohnArnold I don't know what you mean with "double clicked"... a modifier is applied when you click _Apply_ once. Or do you mean the first click when you open the dropdown menu? But that's not clicking _Apply_. There are other options in the menu as well, why would you want the first click always to be meant as _Apply_? And I don't find it confusing... as soon as I apply the modifier I decide that I don't want to change the settings anymore and I switch from the non-destructive modification to the destructive change of the mesh.

Comment: And if I decide to do so, why would I need to know that a modifier had been applied? For example, I could use an _Array_ modifier to duplicate an object a few times. As long as the modifier is not applied, I can change the count and the distance for example. Once I apply it, I lose the possibility of editing those parameters. Now I could get the same result by duplicating an object a few times and afterwards joining them all into one mesh. If I decide to get a mesh with non-editable parameters, what use would it be to know if I created it with a modifier or by simply duplicating?

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann Point taken. Yes once a modifier has been applied there can be no more editing. I was though having problems applying the mirror modifier to my model which is made up of a few different mesh objects some with arrays and even though I selected All when I added a mirror modifier not all of my mesh objects were mirrored and as such I wondered if it was something to do with applying the array modifier and that's when I discovered that my merely having applied ticked did not actually apply it. Is it possible to add a mirror to an entire model which is made up as mine is?

Comment: @JohnArnold An entire model means, consisting of multiple objects? Well, as the other modifiers the _Mirror_ modifier works per object, you have to add it to an object and it mirrors this object. To mirror all objects you have to either join them with Ctrl+J or link the modifiers between objects wirh Ctrl+L, which both might result in losing other non-applied modifiers or adding other modifiers like _Array_ to objects that are not supposed to be arrayed. It also depends on what objects do you mirror, where do you use arrays, how many differently set up modifiers, in which order you apply it.

Comment: @JohnArnold But honestly, this discussion's been going on for much too long. You seem to have a lot of questions on how to work with modifiers which are well worth to be asked separately. The comment section is not suitable for giving tutorials.